# Why i'm Getting the alerts evenafter removing the records from my app in ios?

Tags: ios, notifications, core-location, terminate

I have Created an application that will give notifications when we enter into that area in ios .
and i'm storing those records in SQLITE ,everything is working fine, but after deleting the whole records also I'm getting notifications , Why it is happening?

any explanation could be appreciable..

here is my code...

```
-(void)notifications{

for (int i=0;i<latitudeArray.count; i++) {

centre = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([latitudeArray[i] floatValue], [longitudeArray[i]floatValue]);

    messageToDisplay = cardNameArray[i];

     NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

    if([version floatValue] >= 7.0f) //for iOS7

    {
        regionCourante =  [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:centre
                                                    radius:[radiusArray[i] floatValue]
                                                identifier:@"Radius"];

    }
    else // iOS 7 below
    {
        regionCourante = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centre
                                                      radius:[radiusArray[i] floatValue]
                                                     identifier:@"Radius"];

    }

    imageDataForAlertNotification=cardImageDataArray[i];
    imageString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageDataForAlertNotification encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"image name for notification is %@",imageString);
[manager startMonitoringForRegion:regionCourante];
}
```

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"didEnterRegion %@",region);

```
 UILocalNotification *scheduledAlert;
[UIApplication sharedApplication];
scheduledAlert = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
scheduledAlert.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
scheduledAlert.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
scheduledAlert.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2];
scheduledAlert.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
scheduledAlert.repeatInterval =  NSDayCalendarUnit;
scheduledAlert.alertLaunchImage=@"cardImagePlaceHolder.jpg";
scheduledAlert.alertBody = @"You are near to this are";
 scheduledAlert.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:scheduledAlert];
```

}

Comment: You need to delete the notifications too.

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: i've posted my code..

Comment: yeah may be @rmaddy is right ...b'coz i didn;t set    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]; in my application